# How to dynamically create stage from another class in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Supposedly I have an extended application class to launch from another class

```
public class BasicApp extends Application {
    public static CountDownLatch instanceLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    public static BasicApp instance;

    public synchronized static BasicApp getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            try {
                new Thread(() -> Application.launch(BasicApp.class)).start();
                instanceLatch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public BasicApp () {
        instance = this;
        instanceLatch.countDown();
    }
.
.
.
```

And I want to create multiple instances of the same stage from another class, so I might create a list of stage

```
    private static List<Stage> stages;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        for (Stage st : stages) {
            st.show();
        }
    }
.
.
.
```

so I define a static method to instantiate the stage from another class

```
    public static Stage createStage(String data) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Label(data));
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stages.add(stage);

        return stage;
    }
}
```

However, when I tried to launch the class and create the stage,

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BasicApp app = getInstance();
        app.createStage("Test");
    }
}
```

It threw an exception that says Stage cannot be created outside the FX Application thread.
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;`

The app instance has no problem, yet,
How do I achieve to create the instance of the same stage without getting this error?

Comment: Just.. don't. You're fighting against the API instead of using it as intended. The `start()` method in the one and only application instance that exists is the entry point for the application (it's the place the application starts). Use it as intended. Don't define any other class with a `main(String[] args)` method that does anything other than call `Application.launch()`. You could, e.g., define a `StageManager` class that has your list of `Stage`s and is responsible for instantiating them,  but create an instance of that class in `start()` and pass that instance to anyone who needs it.

Comment: The original reason I did this because I want to launch the app several times. But since the Application is only allowed to launch once, I use this approach. As for the `main(String[] args)`, I didn't use it because I will launch the app using other method call as the string arguments barely used.

Comment: “I want to launch the app several times” is an oxymoron. By definition of “launch”, you can only launch an app once.

Comment: I am clearly aware of that

Comment: Just by that mean, I want to launch the app by creating multiple threads, if you're confused by what I said. But it is prevented

Comment: Like every UI toolkit, JavaFX enforces that all UI operations run on a single thread.

Comment: That's why I create multiple stages. but I am still confused. I will try your suggestion using `StageManager`

Comment: “Stages” and “Threads” are two completely different things. Nothing in your post really talks about multithreading (except that you try to create a stage on the main thread, instead of the JavaFX thread).

Comment: I wish there was an option to upvote "Just.. don't." ten times.

Comment: yeah _Just.. don't_ is THE answer here :) Strongly smells like a xy-problem - what do you __really__ want to achieve?

Comment: Well guys, it worked anyway using @Geoff answer, so I don't mind the approach against the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Platform.runLater()` to execute code on the FX application thread.

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BasicApp app = getInstance();
        Platform.runLater(() -> createStage("Test"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but I don't specifically know how to put the code

Comment: @Zukaru Updated with the example

Comment: This supposedly works, but somehow it didn't run when I run some latches.